# TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I saw a few questions like mine but couldn't find any solutions that worked so I thought I'd ask.

I'm trying to pull all my data from my database so I can select parts of it in my app. I had my database working fine but when I tried to pull the pictures it failed and keeps giving me this error and also does not seem to receive the data from the database:

```html
TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined
```

I have mongoose installed and everything connects so I can't figure out why it won't recognize the find property. My code is below if anyone has any ideas.

```js
// Dependencies
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var exphbs = require("express-handlebars");
var request = require("request");

// var weapons = require("./weapons.js");

// Set mongoose to leverage built in JavaScript ES6 Promises
mongoose.Promise = Promise;


// Initialize Express
var app = express();

// Use morgan and body parser with our app
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));

// Make public a static dir
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.engine("handlebars", exphbs({ defaultLayout: "main" }));
app.set("view engine", "handlebars");

// Database configuration with mongoose
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/weaponsdb");
var db = mongoose.connection;

// Show any mongoose errors
db.on("error", function(error) {
  console.log("Mongoose Error: ", error);
});

// Once logged in to the db through mongoose, log a success message
db.once("open", function() {
  console.log("Mongoose connection successful.");
});
```

```js
//routes to home page

app.get('/', function(req, res, next){

    res.render("index",{ title: 'Express' });

});

app.get('/app', function(req, res, next){

    res.render("app",{ layout: 'applayout' });

});

app.get("/all", function(req, res) {

  // Query: In our database, go to the weapon collection, then "find" everything
  db.weapon.find({}, function(error, found) {

    // Log any errors if the server encounters one
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    // Otherwise, send the result of this query to the browser
    else {
      res.json(found);
    }
  });
});
```

```js
$.getJSON("/all", function(data) {
    console.log(data)
  // For each entry of that json...
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    // Append each of the weapons' properties to the table
    $("#results").append("<img src = " + data[i].Picture + " />");
  }
});
```

Comment: What is the source for `db`?

Comment: You mean the database name correct?

Comment: Why are you using Mongoose to do plain MongoDB queries? If you're not using it as an ORM, I suggest use just mongodb library, you won't need extra dependencies for that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using `mongoose` you should define a `schema` to your collection, and than you can refer to that schema:

```
var weaponSchema = mongoose.Schema({
     .... your model definition here ....
});

var Weapon = mongoose.model('weapon', weaponSchema);
```

Than you can do:

```
Weapon.find({})........
```

Comment: That's likely the case. I had a schema in there but didn't think I needed it for some reason. I'll try adding it back and see if that works for me

Answer (score 4):

For those of you who were interested I figured out the problem.

The issue was the lack of schema which I resolved but also the collection name in mongodb needed to be a plural and not a singular (so weapons not weapon).